# Phonegap app on local network

Tags: php, cordova, xampp

I developed a scan app with phonegap which scans a code, then does an Ajax call to my website which let's the app know whether or not the code is valid (this info is stored in a mysql database).

Now, I want the same functionalities, but on a local network. So I have a computer running a local server using xampp. 
It should be possible to take this setup and place it on a different location (so the ip of the computer can change or should be locked or something).

Anyone who can point me in the right direction, I'm pretty clueless...

Comment: If you have your phone and your computer on the same network (wifi for example), there should not be problems. Maybe a cross domain request issue but this can be solved easily

Comment: So in the app I can link to the ip of the computer? Will this still work when the computer and app are connected to a different local network? Won't the computer get a different ip?

Comment: You must be able to ping from your computer to your phone and vice versa no matter what network you are using. Yes you can put the ip adress of your computer in your ajax call as long as you can reach it from your phone...

Comment: OK, but let's say the computer get's a new ip address for some reason. I don't want to change the ip in de ajax call of the app and rebuild the app every time the computer's ip changes.

Comment: Yeah I understand. To solve this , you can read a file(and edit it when ever your computer get new ip) on your phone which contains the ip adress of your computer and once you read it, you can use it in your ajax. And you won't need to rebuild the app each time. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader

Comment: That should work, thanks!